# React native auto linking is not working (RN0.61.5)

Tags: react-native

Recently I have upgraded from react-native **0.59.1** to **0.61.5** using the `react-native upgrade` command. Previously I was using manual linking for some packages and I had removed it using `react-native unlink` but now it is not working properly when I run on android it builds, but the app only shows the following error

[image]

I'm really new to react-native so I don't know what all to share. So if you need more info just ask.

MainApplication.java

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new 
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a problem of linking, have you removed node_modules and reinstalled them after upgrading? If not, please try it

Comment: share your MainApplication.java code from android folder.. Or check yourself if the module DeviceInfo is added in the list of the packages?

Comment: @Konstantin I have tried that. But didn't work.

Comment: @AnusKaleem I have added my MainApplication.java content please check...

Comment: What version of react-native-device-info are you using? You might need to upgrade all other packages as upgrading react-native version breaks a lot of stuff

Comment: @Konstantin `react-native-device-info: 2.3.2`

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/releases, you should upgrade this package and (maybe) some other packages too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with auto linking in certain versions of ReactNative. All your packages are linked inside your MainApplication.java file. In your file, it is clearly seen that RNDeviceInfo is missing from the list of the packages and I suspect here that it might cause problems for rest of the third-party modules also. I am just mentioning here how to deal with the RNDeviceInfo module. 
Update your source code as:

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo; //Add this import

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new RNDeviceInfo() //add this dependency in the list
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Once you resolve this, same issue might raise for other modules. To resolve, just visit their github repositories and go through the manual linking process for android platform. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my issue. But the react-native-device-info docs says if you are using rn.60 or above autolink will work. I don't understand why it is not working...

Answer (score 1):

to make sure you have the update for version 0.61.5, check out this React-Native update help link https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/.

After that run npm install, try to go to Android folder and run `./gradlew clean` for powershell or`gradlew clean` for cmd.

Comment: If you are having the same problem with IOS, I suggest that you clean your project by XCODE and run pod install in IOS folder

Answer (score 0):

I think this package (react-native-device-info) is not compatible for v0.6 , for example I couldn't migrate react-native-bluetooth-status without manual linking.
but I checked [react-native-device-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info/v/0.9.1) and it has been updated 16 days ago , so I guess if you upgrade your package it links automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled across the same issue -> when you look at a newly initialized project you can see that the `getPackages()` is implemented relying on `PackageList(this).getPackages();` instead of having `new MainReactPackage()` in your list of dependencies.

```
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
  new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };
```